# how to disable a button in react after it is clicked and enable it back when a response is received from backend code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, frontend

1). There is a form with "Save" button
2). When user clicks save - I want the button to be disabled till backend code sends a response that the form was saved successfully.
3). The button should be enabled back after backend provides response

Why do i need this change:- when user clicks on save multiple times(say n) at once - the backend function for same data gets called for n times and data is saved n times. Hence what to handle this - please suggest

Code:

```
           <CustomButton
                save={(e) => console.log('Submitting form...')}
                class='ml-2'
                />
```

CustomButton code:

```
const CustomButton = (props) => {
let className = "button btn btn-sm";
if (props.class) className += ` ${props.class}`;
else className += " mr-2";
return (
    <>
    {props.save ? 
        <Button 
        className={className}
        id="button_success"
        type="submit"
        onClick={e => props.save(e)}
        disabled={props.disable ? props.disable : false}
        >
            Save
        </Button>
    :
```

not familiar with react

Answer (score 2):

A good pattern for this is to handle the disabled/enable outside of the button.

```js
const usage = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const doRequest = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    doTheThing().then(() => {
        // handle request here
    }).finally(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }
  return (<CustomButton
            save={() => doRequest()}
            disable={isLoading}
            class='ml-2'
          />);
}
```

Comment: i dunno what changes to make in our code. This was written ny someone else